# Area 51 - gone down? Other issue?

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

Cannot click on any proposal, no matter whether it is in newest, beta, hottest... well, actually, for a moment I could click on a couple, which  pressed back and another, back and another, to see if they were up, but soon after it was down again, including ones I had previously clicked on.
This is the first time I have visited this site. Looks Very interesting.

Is it down for everyone? Any idea when will it be back up?

Comment: Repro'd and passed along to developers.

Comment: Confirmed - Chrome 12 on Mac OSX 10.6.7.

Comment: Confirmed - I get the `Oops! Something Bad Happened!` error on nearly every page, Chrome `13.0.782.24 beta-m` on Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Well it isn't just me then :) I'll check again later.

Comment: Working for me now.  I could visit the Area 51 Japanese, German, and Skeptics proposals (and no they weren't cached) on OS X Safari 5, along with some other pages I randomly clicked on.  Maybe it was fixed?

Comment: @Troyen - It's still crashing for me on OS X Safari 5. Last I heard, the theory was it might be related to which server you happen to hit.

Answer (score 2):

This should be fixed now, it was indeed related to which server you hit, one of the three web servers that Area 51 is load balanced to was eating it here, so you had a 1/3 chance of being jerked around.

---

*Further reading:*
I restarted the application pool and all is well now, for those curious it's this nasty little bug that pops up occasionally:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Hashtable insert failed. Load factor too high. The most common cause is multiple threads writing to the Hashtable simultaneously.
   at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean add)
   at System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.NodeFor(Type type, Boolean createDelegator)
   at System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(Type type)
   at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinderDictionary.GetBinder(Type modelType, IModelBinder fallbackBinder)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

We've been told it's being worked on by the guys at Microsoft, and it'll be in the next service pack - if it continues to be an issue we'll go the hotfix route.